# Printing QProcess Stdout only if it contains a Substring

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4, qprocess

A PyQt4 app runs `ping` in a `QProcess`. A `QTextEdit` named `self.output` will output everything from `ping`. A second `QTextEdit` named `self.summary` will only output the line if it contains the string `TTL`.

**Problem:** I have managed to get `self.output` working but not `self.summary` as I am not sure how to write its code in the `dataReady` function. Any ideas?

[image]

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore


class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()


    def dataReady(self):
        cursorOutput = self.output.textCursor()
        cursorSummary = self.summary.textCursor()

        cursorOutput.movePosition(cursorOutput.End)
        cursorSummary.movePosition(cursorSummary.End)

        processStdout = str(self.process.readAll())

        # Update self.output
        cursorOutput.insertText(processStdout)

        # Update self.summary
        for line in processStdout:
            if 'TTL' in line:
                cursorSummary.insertText(line)


        self.output.ensureCursorVisible()
        self.summary.ensureCursorVisible()


    def callProgram(self):
        self.process.start('ping', ['127.0.0.1'])


    def initUI(self):
        layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.runBtn = QtGui.QPushButton('Run')
        self.runBtn.clicked.connect(self.callProgram)

        self.output = QtGui.QTextEdit()
        self.summary = QtGui.QTextEdit()

        layout.addWidget(self.runBtn)
        layout.addWidget(self.output)
        layout.addWidget(self.summary)

        centralWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
        centralWidget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        # QProcess object for external app
        self.process = QtCore.QProcess(self)
        self.process.readyRead.connect(self.dataReady)
        self.process.started.connect(lambda: self.runBtn.setEnabled(False))
        self.process.finished.connect(lambda: self.runBtn.setEnabled(True))


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem that you could have is that each output of `QProcess` could have several lines, ie contain `"\n"`, to not have that problem we separate it, and then we do the search:

```
for line in processStdout.split("\n"):
    if "TTL" in line:
        cursorSummary.insertText(line+"\n")
```

In your initial code you are getting each character with the for loop, which is generating the error.

[image]

*Note:* In linux I have to filter by the word `ttl`. In addition to changing the QProcess to: `self.process.start('ping', ['-c', '3', '127.0.0.1'])`