# PyQt4/QProcess issues with Nuke v9

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4, nuke

PyQt4/QProcess issues with Nuke v9...

I am trying to utilize a QProcess to run renders in Nuke at my workplace. The reason why I want to use a QProcess is because I've setup this Task Manager with the help of the community at stackoverflow, which takes a list of commands and sequentially runs it one by one, and also allows me to display an output. You can view the question I posted here:

[How to update UI with output from QProcess loop without the UI freezing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58741020/how-to-update-ui-with-output-from-qprocess-loop-without-the-ui-freezing)

Now I am trying to basically run Nuke renders through this "Task Manager". But every time I do it just gives me an error that the QProcess is destroyed while still running. I mean I tested this with subprocess and that worked totally fine. So i am not sure why the renders are not working through QProcess.

So to do more testing I just wrote a simplified version at home. The first issue I ran into though is that apparently PyQt4 couldn't be found from Nuke's python.exe. Even though I have PyQt4 for my main Python version. However apparently there is a compatibility issue with my installed PyQt4 since my main Python version is 2.7.12, while my Nuke's python version is 2.7.3. So i thought "fine then i'll just directly install PyQt4 inside my Nuke directory". So i grabbed this link and installed this PyQt version into my Nuke directory:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt4/PyQt-4.10.3/PyQt4-4.10.3-gpl-Py2.7-Qt4.8.5-x64.exe

So i run my little test and seems to be doing the same thing as it does in my workplace, where the QProcess just gets destoryed. So i thought maybe adding "waitForFinished()" would maybe do something different, but then it gives me this error that reads:

```
The procedure entry point ??4QString@@QEAAAEAV0@$$QEAV0@@Z could not be located in the dynamic link library QtCore4.dll
```

And gives me this error as well:

ImportError: Failed to load C:\Program Files\Nuke9.0v8\nuke-9.0.8.dll

Now at this point I can't really do any more testing at home, and my studio is closed for the holidays. So i have two questions i'd like to ask:

1) What is this error I am seeing about "procedure entry point"? It only happens when i try to call something in a QProcess instance.

2) Why is my QProcess being destroyed before the render is finished?? How come this doesn't happen with subprocess? How can I submit a Nuke render job while acheiving the same results as subprocess?

Here is my test code:

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess
import PyQt4
from PyQt4 import QtCore

class Task:
    def __init__(self, program, args=None):
        self._program = program
        self._args = args or []

    @property
    def program(self):
        return self._program

    @property
    def args(self):
        return self._args


class SequentialManager(QtCore.QObject):
    started = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    progressChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    dataChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    #^ this is how we can send a signal and can declare what type
    # of information we want to pass with this signal

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        # super(SequentialManager, self).__init__(parent)
        # QtCore.QObject.__init__(self,parent)
        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self)

        self._progress = 0
        self._tasks = []
        self._process = QtCore.QProcess(self)
        self._process.setProcessChannelMode(QtCore.QProcess.MergedChannels)
        self._process.finished.connect(self._on_finished)
        self._process.readyReadStandardOutput.connect(self._on_readyReadStandardOutput)

    def execute(self, tasks):
        self._tasks = iter(tasks)
        #this 'iter()' method creates an iterator object
        self.started.emit()
        self._progress = 0
        self.progressChanged.emit(self._progress)
        self._execute_next()

    def _execute_next(self):
        try:
            task = next(self._tasks)
        except StopIteration:
            return False
        else:
            print 'starting %s' % task.args
            self._process.start(task.program, task.args)
            return True

    def _on_finished(self):
        self._process_task()
        if not self._execute_next():
            self.finished.emit()

    def _on_readyReadStandardOutput(self):
        output = self._process.readAllStandardOutput()
        result = output.data().decode()
        self.dataChanged.emit(result)

    def _process_task(self):
        self._progress += 1
        self.progressChanged.emit(self._progress)


class outputLog(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, parentWindow=None):
        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self)
        self._manager = SequentialManager(self)

    def startProcess(self, tasks):
        # self._manager.progressChanged.connect(self._progressbar.setValue)
        self._manager.dataChanged.connect(self.on_dataChanged)
        self._manager.started.connect(self.on_started)
        self._manager.finished.connect(self.on_finished)
        self._manager.execute(tasks)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_started(self):
        print 'process started'

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_finished(self):
        print 'finished'

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def on_dataChanged(self, message):
        if message:
            print message

def nukeTestRender():
    import nuke

    nuke.scriptOpen('D:/PC6/Documents/nukeTestRender/nukeTestRender.nk')

    writeNode = None
    for node in nuke.allNodes():
        if node.Class() == 'Write':
            writeNode = node

    framesList = [1, 20, 30, 40]
    fr = nuke.FrameRanges(framesList)
    # nuke.execute(writeNode, fr)

    for x in range(20):
        print 'random'

def run():
    nukePythonEXE = 'C:/Program Files/Nuke9.0v8/python.exe'
    thisFile = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath("__file__"))
    print thisFile
    cmd = '"%s" %s renderCheck' %(nukePythonEXE, __file__)
    cmd2 = [__file__, 'renderCheck']
    cmdList = [Task(nukePythonEXE, cmd2)]
    # subprocess.call(cmd, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, shell=False)
    taskManager = outputLog()
    taskManager.startProcess(cmdList)
    taskManager._manager._process.waitForFinished()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print sys.argv
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        run()
    elif len(sys.argv) == 2:
        nukeTestRender()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to come up with an answer, so I will write in the details below:

Basically, I was getting the error with the installed PyQt4 because it was not compatible with my version of Nuke, so it is apparently more recommended to use PySide included in Nuke. However Nuke's Python executable cannot natively find PySide, a few paths needed to be added to the sys.path:

```
paths = ['C:\\Program Files\\Nuke9.0v8\\lib\\site-packages,
C:\\Users\\Desktop02\\.nuke',
'C:\\Program Files\\Nuke9.0v8\\plugins',
'C:\\Program Files\\Nuke9.0v8\\pythonextensions\\site-packages\\setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg',
'C:\\Program Files\\Nuke9.0v8\\pythonextensions\\site-packages\\protobuf-2.5.0-py2.6.egg',
'C:\\Program Files\\Nuke9.0v8\\pythonextensions\\site-packages',
'C:\\Program Files\\Nuke9.0v8\\plugins\\modules',
'C:\\Program Files\\Nuke9.0v8\\configs\\Python\\site-packages',
'C:\\Users\\Desktop02\\.nuke\\Python\\site-packages']

for path in paths:
   sys.path.append(path)
```

I found the missing paths by opening up both Nuke in GUI mode and the Python executable, and comparing both sys.path to see what the Python executable was lacking.

And to answer my own main question: if I call waitForFinished(-1) on the QProcess instance, this ignores the default 30sec limit of this function... Answer came from this thread:

[QProcess and shell : Destroyed while process is still running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14504201/qprocess-and-shell-destroyed-while-process-is-still-running)

So here is my resulting working code:

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess
sysArgs = sys.argv
try:
    import nuke
    from PySide import QtCore
except ImportError:
    raise ImportError('nuke not currently importable')

class Task:
    def __init__(self, program, args=None):
        self._program = program
        self._args = args or []

    @property
    def program(self):
        return self._program

    @property
    def args(self):
        return self._args


class SequentialManager(QtCore.QObject):
    started = QtCore.Signal()
    finished = QtCore.Signal()
    progressChanged = QtCore.Signal(int)
    dataChanged = QtCore.Signal(str)
    #^ this is how we can send a signal and can declare what type
    # of information we want to pass with this signal

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        # super(SequentialManager, self).__init__(parent)
        # QtCore.QObject.__init__(self,parent)
        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self)

        self._progress = 0
        self._tasks = []
        self._process = QtCore.QProcess(self)
        self._process.setProcessChannelMode(QtCore.QProcess.MergedChannels)
        self._process.finished.connect(self._on_finished)
        self._process.readyReadStandardOutput.connect(self._on_readyReadStandardOutput)

    def execute(self, tasks):
        self._tasks = iter(tasks)
        #this 'iter()' method creates an iterator object
        self.started.emit()
        self._progress = 0
        self.progressChanged.emit(self._progress)
        self._execute_next()

    def _execute_next(self):
        try:
            task = next(self._tasks)
        except StopIteration:
            return False
        else:
            print 'starting %s' % task.args
            self._process.start(task.program, task.args)
            return True

    def _on_finished(self):
        self._process_task()
        if not self._execute_next():
            self.finished.emit()

    def _on_readyReadStandardOutput(self):
        output = self._process.readAllStandardOutput()
        result = output.data().decode()
        self.dataChanged.emit(result)

    def _process_task(self):
        self._progress += 1
        self.progressChanged.emit(self._progress)


class outputLog(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, parentWindow=None):
        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self)
        self._manager = SequentialManager(self)

    def startProcess(self, tasks):
        # self._manager.progressChanged.connect(self._progressbar.setValue)
        self._manager.dataChanged.connect(self.on_dataChanged)
        self._manager.started.connect(self.on_started)
        self._manager.finished.connect(self.on_finished)
        self._manager.execute(tasks)

    @QtCore.Slot()
    def on_started(self):
        print 'process started'

    @QtCore.Slot()
    def on_finished(self):
        print 'finished'

    @QtCore.Slot(str)
    def on_dataChanged(self, message):
        if message:
            print message

def nukeTestRender():
    import nuke

    nuke.scriptOpen('D:/PC6/Documents/nukeTestRender/nukeTestRender.nk')

    writeNode = None
    for node in nuke.allNodes():
        if node.Class() == 'Write':
            writeNode = node

    framesList = [1, 20, 30, 40]
    fr = nuke.FrameRanges(framesList)
    nuke.execute(writeNode, fr)
    # nuke.execute(writeNode, start=1, end=285)

    for x in range(20):
        print 'random'

def run():
    nukePythonEXE = 'C:/Program Files/Nuke9.0v8/python.exe'
    thisFile = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath("__file__"))
    print thisFile
    cmd = '"%s" %s renderCheck' %(nukePythonEXE, sysArgs[0])
    cmd2 = [sysArgs[0], 'renderCheck']
    cmdList = [Task(nukePythonEXE, cmd2)]
    # subprocess.call(cmd, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, shell=False)
    taskManager = outputLog()
    taskManager.startProcess(cmdList)
    taskManager._manager._process.waitForFinished(-1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print sys.argv
    if len(sysArgs) == 1:
        run()
    elif len(sysArgs) == 2:
        nukeTestRender()
```

For whatever reason, PySide refuses to load for me without the nuke module imported first. and also theres a known error when importing nuke it deletes all sys.argv arguments so thats gotta be stored somewhere first before the nuke import...